# importing neo4j graphml into orientdb issue

Tags: neo4j, orientdb

I have a simple dbpl database containing two classes.

1. author
2. publication

and they are related by the edge published_by.

author has two properties, (key , name)
and publication has four properties, (key, name, type, year)

I generated the graphml from neo4j and imported it into orientdb as described [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Import-from-Neo4j-into-OrientDB.html).

But the orientdb imported the data in strange way, it creates two classes,

1. author
2. publication

but author class only contain (key), and publication class only contain (key, type and year). and they have no connectivity between them.

The orientdb do created the edge class by name published_by but in and out properties of published_by are pointing to some other type of vertices class named V.

Sorry for my bad english, and if you know any thing related to this please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1- You could create the property in the app of OrientDB and do this import.

2- You could export the Neo4j DB in CSV. After this, you will put the data from CSV to a project Java or Python. Too easy. After this, you can do a method POST to import the data in the DB (I did it).

3- You could export the DB and import in OrientDB using the ETL that OrientDB community have in gist.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB does not like "id" as keys in the database, it will maintain its own id for each record something like `#<cluster-id>:<cluster-position>`.

What you should do is first update the `id` attributes to `uid` or something else in neo4j and export it to graphml and import into orientDB.